# Jenkins pipeline - only look at Jenkinsfile, don't pull git project?

Tags: jenkins

Basically, I have a Jenkinsfile on my github which I would like Jenkins to look at and execute the script. However, when I create a pipeline item and set it up, it pulls the entire project instead of just the Jenkinsfile. How would I just pull the jenkinsfile and make it execute the groovy code in the Jenkinsfile?

Comment: i dont think you can do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting up a Jenkins pipeline from git there is an option for a light weight checkout at the bottom of the pipeline from SCM configuration box ( I would add an image but I'm on a mobile)

This will pull just the Jenkinsfile from the repository. Is this what you mean by just checking out the pipeline rather than the whole repository.

Comment: Interesting. Thing is, when I enable lightweight checkout, the git branch checkout behavior changes WRT the branch setting. I set the branch setting to ${GIT_BRANCH} so that I can specify it via a parameter. Without lightweight checkout this works; pulling the branch specified via param GIT_BRANCH, but with lightweight checkout it tries to checkout a branch called "${GIT_BRANCH}" which obviously fails. So, I guess due to this behavior (that I consider a bug) I guess I have to live with a full repo checkout for the jenkinsfile :(

Comment: That does sounds like a bug to me, the lightweight option should observe the branch option, does it do this when the branch is set manually ( I believe we used master and development so I believe from memory it does work on set strings) ? if so file a bug, I no longer work with Jenkins or have access to a jenkins job to test this.

Comment: On logging a bug, I found this https://issues.jenkins.io/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/JENKINS-28447 and https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-42971 which describe the issue. But marked resolved. Maybe there are multiple parts/aspects to the bug. So, going to log a new one and reference this one. One thing I don't get with Jenkins is I have to pick a component, but how is someone supposed to know what component has a bug? That's for a Jenkins developer to figure out. grumble grumble. ... created one; but can't find the number; nothing comes up for 'my open issues' (arg)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is work on a branch and when you are proud of your Jenkinsfile, merge it on master branch.

Another way of doing would be to have a separate repository for your Jenkinsfiles/jobs. Depending on the project you work on and your needs, the second solution could be the best choice. To automate the generation of pipeline jobs on jenkins, I use  https://github.com/SAP/jenkins-pipelayer